# How do you have a main page with out a tab bar and then on one of the pages add a tab bar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode4

My program has a main page that is a menu.  After the user selects one of the buttons it goes into a tab bar.  I can't figure out how to do this, everything I keep finding is for the entire program to be a tab bar.

Comment: It's easy, have your main view controller be inside navigation controller, and push the tab bar controller within that navigation controller when you want to.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

UIViewController *controller1 = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"View1" bundle:nil];
controller1.title = @"View1";

UIViewController *controller2 = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"View2" bundle:nil];
controller1.title = @"View2";

tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:controller1,controller2,nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBarController];

[controller1 release];
[controller2 release];
[tabBarController release];
```

Comment: Do I have to add extra code in order to use the push View Controller?